# Why cant i assign at next line?

Tags: java, string, object

Why does the following compiles

```
class Foo {
    Object x;
    String s = (String) x;
}
```

and the following does not compile?

```
class Foo {
    Object x;
    String s;
    s = (String) x;
}
```

Am I missing some `JLS` rules? I know this must be silly but still I need to know the reason behind this.

Comment: You cannot write assignments outside of methods. Put `s = (String) x` within a constructor and it will compile.

Comment: Seems like you can't assign values to a variable without a type outside of a block.

Comment: why does java forces to do this? any security reasons? an example would be nice

Comment: @ShubhamKharde the question is: why would you want to write the not-compiling case? For initialization, you have the constructor.

Comment: @Turing85 I was just fondling around and came by this. My question was why first condition was allowed and second wasn't. And thanks for clearing that doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The `non-static` block (here marked as  `{ }` ) has access to the `variables`, and `methods`. And this block is called during the `constructor` execution, just after the call to the `super class constructor`.**

Hence, initializations can be made in this block.

You can either `initialize` instance variables along with the declaration, in one line, or inside of a `non-static block`.

Then, this `initialization` takes place as soon as the `constructor` is called.
(Because, it follows the execution of the code in the block).

Hence, the block is effectively a part of the `constructor` execution.

On the other hand if you write your initialization code in the class itself, it has no meaning, as no method ever executes that line, hence is incorrect.

So, **Method 1 : Initialization Along with Declaration :**

```
class Foo {
    Object x;
    String s = (String) x;
}
```

Or, **Method 2 : Initialization in block, after declaration :**

```
class Foo {
    Object x;
    String s;
    {
        s = (String) x;
    }
}
```

Remember, this non-static block is called during constructor execution, after the call to the super class constructor.

Comment: Thanks.Your answer adds more to my beginner's knowledge.

Comment: @ShubhamKharde [Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

You could use an *instance level block*

```
{
    s = (String) x;
}
```

assignment statements should belong to a block if they are not on part of the *declaration* statement.
 A *block* could be anything (a method, constructor etc)

Comment: Thanks.I think i got the reason behind this.To ensure encapsulation? isn't it? By doing so we are modifying the field only within methods or blocks.

Comment: No. Not encapsulation.. Its just how the language structure was designed.

Answer (score 2):

In general, a class declaration can only contain class body declarations. These are:

- Field declarations
- Method declarations
- Class declarations (of classes defined within your class)
- Interface declarations
- Instance initializers
- Static initializers
- Constructor declarations.

The line

```
s = (String) x;
```

is none of those.

You could use an initializer declaration as suggested by @TheLostMind, or put the assignment into a constructor as suggested by @Turing85. You could also put such a line into some other method. You could even do something ridiculous like this:

```
class Foo {
Object x;
String s;
String s2 = s = (String) x;
}
```

The lines declaring x, s and s2 are all field declarations. The weird stuff after the first "=" on the s2 line is all the initializer of s2. And the assignment expression `s = (String) x` is a legal expression that returns a String, so it fits there.

But an unadorned `s = (String) x;` is a statement, not a class body declaration, so it just can't go there per the rules of Java (a.k.a. the Java Language Specification).